# How to write UI Tests without view ids in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-espresso

I am using data binding for my projects so there is no need to assign ids as I am setting almost everything in xml or via BindingAdapters.

Now when I want to automate UI Tests for which I will need to find views via Ids, or some other view properties. The other view properties may not be that good. So is it suggested to assign ids to views just for testing?
Also considering if I don't assign ids I may be saving few bytes in R.Java files.

So how should I go with?

Comment: Worrying about saving a few bytes when using Java which wastes 4 per reference is a little silly, don't you think?

Comment: @GabeSechan It was just a thought, I am not just removing ids just because of saving 4 bytes, Databinding worked the way so ids got removed.
So what is your opinion ids should be retained?